Flutter when i try to run windows app i got cmake error
When i try run windows app i get error. But I can run it on the web or android/ios
Error:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (target_compile_features):   Cannot
specify compile features for target "flutter_wrapper_plugin" which
is not built by this project. Call Stack (most recent call first):
flutter/CMakeLists.txt:56 (apply_standard_settings)
CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:57 (set_target_properties):
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
flutter_wrapper_plugin
CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:59 (set_target_properties):
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
flutter_wrapper_plugin
CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:61 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "flutter_wrapper_plugin"
which is   not built by this project.
Exception: Unable to generate build files

